# Django channels elastic beanstalk (linux 2) hooks postdeploy: -b command not found

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-channels, django-deployment

For deployment of django channels on elastic beanstalk (linux 2 AMI) I tried implementing this  [blog](https://hashnode.com/login?next=https://blog.zishanahmad.dev/how-to-deploy-django-channels-2x-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-amazon-linux-2) ,it required creation of ./platform/hooks/postdeploy/ and in it two files 01_set_env.sh and 02_run_supervisor_daemon.sh, on **eb deploy** it fails and on checking the eb-engine.logs  this error shows up.

```
    2021/09/28 05:05:44.382229 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks]. Stop running the command. Error: Command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/02_run_supervisor_daemon.sh failed with error exit status 2. Stderr:.platform/hooks/postdeploy/02_run_supervisor_daemon.sh: line 13: -b: command not found
```

02_run_supervisor_daemon.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get system environment variables
systemenv=`cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/custom_env_var | tr '
' ',' | sed 's/%/%%/g' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/:$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'`
systemenv=${systemenv%?}
systemenv=`echo $systemenv | sed 's/,/",/g' | sed 's/=/="/g'`
systemenv="$systemenv""


# Create daemon configuration script
daemonconf="[program:daphne]

command=daphne -b :: -p 5000 backend.asgi:application

directory=/var/app
user=ec2-user
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/stdout_daphne.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/stderr_daphne.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

environment=$systemenv"

# Create the Supervisor conf script
echo "$daemonconf" | sudo tee /etc/supervisor/conf.d/daemon.conf

# Reread the Supervisor config
supervisorctl reread

# Update Supervisor in cache without restarting all services
supervisorctl update

# Start/restart processes through Supervisor
supervisorctl restart daphne
```

01_set_env.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#Create a copy of the environment variable file.
cp /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/custom_env_var

#Set permissions to the custom_env_var file so this file can be accessed by any user on the instance. You can restrict permissions as per your requirements.
chmod 644 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/custom_env_var

#Remove duplicate files upon deployment.
rm -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/*.bak
```

Would be great if you could suggest some resources for the deployment of Django channels on ebs(linux 2 as most blogs are for linux1) as well.